# How do I disable Forecasts?

Tags: forecast

I accidentally enabled Forecasts in my salesforce Org. I am trying to disable it. However, going to Build > Customize > Forecasts > Forecasts Settings, I am unable to uncheck "Enable Forecasts". I am a System Admin as well.

Is there a way to disable forecasts?

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_sharing_disable_tm.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't disable forecasts yourself. There should be a help icon next to the 'Enable' box. Hovering over that will tell you that you need to contact Salesforce support to disable forecasts.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Setup- add on the quick search 'Forecasts' -- forecast settings - click on the Enable tick box, that should be clicked, and it will be back to disable.

Comment: Hi Viasur. Like I said in my original post, I am unable to uncheck that box. It does not let me.

Comment: Yup, you need to contact Salesforce to disable it.